# Connecting to a server running in local machine with IP fails

Tags: networking, debian

I am running Tomcat server on port let's 8080 in my local machine(Debian). when I run curl http://localhost:8080 get a response as expected, but when I use my machine's IP, I get **connection refused** error. With browser also the same.

When I ping it either with IP or localhost, I get the response without any problem

IP for my machine is 192.168.1.1

The IP Lookup table is as follow

[image]

Comment: You need to configure Tomcat to listen on the IP address interface as well as localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tomcat is probably to bind to 127.0.0.1, which is the local loopback. Try configuring to bind to 0.0.0.0 instead. This should make it accessible from all of the macine's addresses.